# How to validate and verify jmeter results for performance testing

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

After jmeter testing, i have graph result,summary report and view result in tree in this how i can say that performance of the application is good.

Answer (score 0):

I explained a usecase and steps to validate the performance of sample webpage.

**UseCase:** Assume that your application has Authentication/Login screen which accepts username and password .

JMeter TestCases:
**Step-1:** Test the login validation screen with 1 http request call and measure the response time.
**Step-2:** Test the login validation screen with 10 http request calls (concurently) and measure the response time
**Step-3:** Test the login validation screen with no of request calls specific to your Project's Non Functional requirement and measure the response time.

**Expected result:**
The response time of login validation screen will be increased based on no of concurrent request calls and it may reach the max response time specified by non functional requirement.